# progress bar with $.ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, progress-bar

I'm trying to make a progress bar which works with $.ajax(jquery) and php for a file uploader but I dont know how to assemble it. I know there is a progress bar working with jQuery UI; how ever, it just change while receiving a value. And that's the point. How can I get a dinamic value for the byte uploded?

By the way, this is my code:

---

fx_file.js

```
/*This function gets Data from the form and send it to server*/
function fiEnviarDatos2(){
    $("form#data").click(function(){
            /*Some DOM'S animations*/
    });

    $("form#data").submit(function(){

    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: "PHP/Core/Archivos/upload.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    async: false,
                    success: function (data) {

                        /*After actions**/

                    },
                    progress:function(data){
                        alert(data);
                    },
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false
    });
return false;
});`
```

---

upload.php

---

```
<?php include ("Class_upload.php");

 /*Variables*/
$i=0;
$archivos=0;

/*Contains numbers of file sent*/
$archivos=((count($_FILES,1)-6)/5);

/*Contains the user's session name*/
session_start();
$sUsuario=$_SESSION['usuario'];

/*Use the information of each file to create a new class Upload*/
for($i=0;$i<$archivos;$i++){

    /*FileSize*/
    $tamaArchivo = $_FILES['formUploader']['size'][$i];

    /*Filename*/
    $nombArchivo = strtolower($_FILES['formUploader']['name'][$i]);

    /*Filetemp*/
    $tmpArchivo = $_FILES['formUploader']['tmp_name'][$i];

    /*It creates class Upload*/
    $archivo_subir=new Upload($nombArchivo,$tamaArchivo,$tmpArchivo,$sUsuario);

    /*It validates each file and returns a status*/
    $estatus=$archivo_subir->enviarData();

    /*Returns if file's been uploaded or not*/
    $resultFile=$archivo_subir->resultFile($estatus);
    echo "<br>";
    if($estatus>0){
        echo "<div class='resultDeny'>".$resultFile."</div>";
    }else{
        if($resultFile=="ServerError"){
            echo "<div class='resultServer'>".$resultFile."</div>";
        }else{
            echo "<div class='resultSuccess'>".$resultFile."</div>";
        }

    }

}
```

---

I hope I can found some help from you, guys. I know you all are expert. I'm new working with jquery and php; however , i've seen "their power together" and i want to learn more about them.

Thanks for all.

PDT: Sorry for my english, it's not my mother language. JQ &PHP will be.

Comment: Are you using an option that supports upload progress? Either php 5.4 or APC?

Comment: I don't know how to achieve this using jQuerry, but the callback for upload status is `HTTPRequest.upload.onprogress`. The callback gets `event` as the first parameter and the progress in percent is obtained this way: `event.loaded * 100 / event.total`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. Well, i'm using php 5.4, does it influence anything?

Comment: HTTPRequest? I'd wolud like if you post and example with that line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this page out: 
http://www.johnboy.com/php-upload-progress-bar/
http://www.johnboy.com/php-upload-progress-bar/upload_frame.phps
basically

```
        function(data)    //return information back from jQuery's get request
        {
            $('#progress_container').fadeIn(100);    //fade in progress bar    
            $('#progress_bar').width(data +"%");    //set width of progress bar based on the $status value (set at the top of this page)
            $('#progress_completed').html(parseInt(data) +"%");    //display the % completed within the progress bar
        }
    )},500);
```

Comment: Yep, thanks for the answer Willian, I saw your example yesterday while looking for some information; however, in order to use that , i 'd have to use $.get instead of $.ajax. I think if i change the protocol for sending data may cause more problems. :/

Answer (score 2):

after investigating almost all day , I achieved what I wanted.

I found this plugin called JQUERY Form Plugin.
[http://malsup.com/jquery/form/][1]

Maybe some of you have used it. It has almost all the necessary options to built a progressbar and to introduce code before and after submitting the form.

So, check it out. Maybe someone finds it useful

Btw , this is how my code looks like now

**accountUser.html**

---

```
<html>
//...

...//
<style>

 form { display: block; margin: 20px auto; background: #eee; border-radius: 10px; padding: 15px }
.progress { position:relative; width:400px; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 1px; border-radius: 3px; margin-top:-200px }
.bar { background-image:url(Imagenes/index/pbar-ani.gif); width:0%; height:20px; border-    radius: 3px; }
.percent { position:absolute; display:inline-block; top:3px; left:48%; }

</style>

<script language="javascript" src="Scripts/jquery_min_1.8.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="Scripts/fx_file.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>

//...

..//
<form  action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formu">
    <input name="formUploader[]" type="file" multiple id="archivo"/>
   <input class="button" type="submit" alt="Upload" value="Subir" id="btn_cargar"/>
</form>

<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div >
    <div class="percent">0%</div >
</div>

//...

..//
</html>
```

**fx_file.js**

---

```
$(document).ready(function() { 


        // prepare Options Object 
        var bar = $('.bar');
        var percent = $('.percent');
        var status = $('#status');

        var options = { 
            url:  "upload.php", 
            type: 'POST',
            uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                $(bar).animate({width:percentVal});
                percent.html(percentVal);

            },
            success: function(data){

                    //After actions

            }
        }; 
        // bind 'formu' and provide a simple callback function 
       $('#formu').ajaxForm(options);
});
```

**upload.php**

---

```
<?php include ("Class_upload.php");

/*Variables*/
$i=0;
$archivos=0;

/*Contains numbers of file sent*/
$archivos=((count($_FILES,1)-6)/5);

/*Contains the user's session name*/
session_start();
$sUsuario=$_SESSION['usuario'];

/*Use the information of each file to create a new class Upload*/
for($i=0;$i<$archivos;$i++){

      /*FileSize*/
      $tamaArchivo = $_FILES['formUploader']['size'][$i];

      /*Filename*/
      $nombArchivo = strtolower($_FILES['formUploader']['name'][$i]);

      /*Filetemp*/
      $tmpArchivo = $_FILES['formUploader']['tmp_name'][$i];

      /*It creates class Upload*/
      $archivo_subir=new Upload($nombArchivo,$tamaArchivo,$tmpArchivo,$sUsuario);

      /*It validates each file and returns a status*/
      $estatus=$archivo_subir->enviarData();

      /*Returns if file's been uploaded or not*/
      $resultFile=$archivo_subir->resultFile($estatus);
      echo "<br>";

      if($estatus>0){
            echo "<div class='resultDeny'>".$resultFile."</div>";
      }else{
         if($resultFile=="ServerError"){
            echo "<div class='resultServer'>".$resultFile."</div>";
         }else{
            echo "<div class='resultSuccess'>".$resultFile."</div>";
         }

      }

}//End For

<?php>
```